Unable to connect using openvpn in ubuntu 23.10 desktop
websites are not loading if I enable my OpenVPN in Ubuntu 23.10. syslog entries are not showing any errors.
Exact versions of ubuntu and OpenVPN have been given below
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 23.10"
OpenVPN 2.6.5 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] [DCO]
library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.10 1 Aug 2023, LZO 2.10

OpenVPN conf
➜  ~ cat Downloads/openvpn-ChijuChandran-inline.ovpn
client
resolv-retry 20
keepalive 10 60
nobind
mute-replay-warnings
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
max-routes 500
verb 1
persist-key
persist-tun
explicit-exit-notify 1
dev tun
auth-user-pass
proto udp
port 1194
cipher AES-128-CBC
remote x.x.x.x 1194 # public address 

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.....
.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>

<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
.....
.....
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>

